# How will Push Sync work with S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently developing the android app in which there are two users, consider Employer and Employee. In app, there is functionality where Employer will upload any file from app and it will store in AWS S3 bucket. Now I want, whenever employer upload any file, all the employees' app will be notified and the file will be downloaded in device.

Please help, How will I achieve through Push Sync OR any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: let your server manage this... As file gets uploded on server send GCM or FCM to all your devices and in which you can download that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with AWS SNS (Simple Notification Service). Once you configure with your S3 bucket, if any updates to your s3 bucket it will gets automatically trigger. From there call any of your service / API / Lambda function to send notifications.